# How to generate a token for different workspaces in same Power BI embedding app

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have one Power BI report in Workspace 1 and two Power BI datasets in Workspace 2.

Is is possible to generate tokens where I can embedded Power BI report from Workspace 1 and can dynamically bind dataset from Workspace 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate token for your dataset and report using following API

`POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken`

The request body should contain the following:

```js
{
  datasets: [{ id: "IdOfRequiredDataset" }],
  reports: [{ id: "IdofRequiredReport" }],
  targetWorkspaces: [
    { id: "WorkspaceIdofReport" },
    { id: "WorkspaceIdOfDataset" },
  ],
}
```

Now you can dynamically bind dataset to your report as long as the datasets have same data schema.
To bind different datasets using dynamic binding, add the datasetBinding property to the embed configuration object.

Please refer to below code snippet:

```js
const reportConfig = {
        type: 'report',
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
        accessToken: "tokenGeneratedByAPI", // Access token returned by generate token API
        embedUrl: embedParams.EmbedReport[0].EmbedUrl,
        // Adding datasetBinding property
        datasetBinding: {
            datasetId: "datasetId", // ID of dataset that you want the report to use
        },
    };

// Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element.
let embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0]; 

// Embed the report and display it within the div container.
let report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);
```

Report before using datasetBinding (uses report's original dataset):
[image]

Report after using datasetBinding (binding report to other dataset):
[image]

You can also refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/bind-report-datasets